# Make available port 137 on Wine applications

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, proxy, wine

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 + Wine 2.18 (development version).

CCProxy is a proxy server for Windows. It is compatible with Wine, and [officially mentioned](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/ccproxy-in-linux.htm).

I tried and run CCProxy in Wine, everything seems OK, but unfortunately one feature does not work... CCProxy cannot get client's MAC address for authentication. Also the solution to this problem is mentioned in [CCProxy's website](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/faq_82.htm):

> CCProxy uses port 137 to get client's MAC address for authentication.
> So you need to make sure port 137 is available on both CCProxy server
> and client. Sometimes, antivirus software and firewall may block port
> 137, please check it out.
>
> On the other hand, you also need to install NetBIOS protocol on the client.

The problem is I don't know what to do, and what I supposed to do!

**Edit:**

```
$ sudo iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: MAC addresses aren’t related to ports at all. Sounds very strange, all in all. If you just want a proxy, there are plenty available natively on Linux.

Comment: Well, there _is_ a query that can be used via NetBIOS to get a computer's "main" MAC address... but that actually brings a bigger problem: it's going to be only compatible with Windows clients, and only those which haven't turned off SMBv1 yet. (That and it's very easy to spoof.)